# Can we always let two uncommute hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$ commute by enlarge the dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

For example, we have two hermitian matrices $$A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 1&  0\\
 0&  -1\\
\end{matrix} \right) ,B=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  1\\
 1&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) .$$
And for this special case, I can find another two hermitian matrices by placing $A$ and $B$ as the principal submatrix commute as follows:
$$\tilde{A}=\left( \begin{matrix}
 1&  0&  -1\\
 0&  -1&  1\\
 -1&  1&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) ,\tilde{B}=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  1&  1\\
 1&  0&  1\\
 1&  1&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) .$$
I wonder if there exists general theorems guarantee that we can always find two enlarged commuting hermitian matrix like this?

Comment: To expand 2x2 hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$ to 3x3 hermitian matrices you need to add 3 variable elements to each (last column or last row, same thing), which means 6 unknowns.  But commutators of hermitian matrices are anti-symmetric, which means that you get only 3 equations to zero that commutator. Even though these equations are not linear the probability of having a solution is rather high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial answer. Every pair of Hermitian $n\times n$ matrices can be embedded, as leading principal submatrices, in a pair of commuting Hermitian $m\times m$ matrices when $m\ge 2n-1$.

For convenience, I will call your two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ (instead of $A$ and $B$). When $c>0$ is sufficiently large, $A_1+cI_n$ is positive definite. Hence $A_1+cI_n$ and $A_2+cI_n$ are simultaneously diagonalisable by congruence. That is, there exists a nonsingular matrix $P$ and two real diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ such that $A_i+cI_n=PD_iP^\ast$ for each $i$. By absorbing an appropriate positive factor into $P$ and its inverse factor into $D_1$ and $D_2$, we may assume that $\|P\|_2=1$. Hence $\operatorname{rank}(I_n-P^\ast P)\le n-1\le\min(m-n,\,n)$ and there exists an $(m-n)\times n$ matrix $Q$ such that $Q^\ast Q=I_n-P^\ast P$. Thus $\pmatrix{P\\ Q}$ has orthonormal columns and we can complete it to a unitary matrix $U=\pmatrix{P&\ast\\ Q&\ast}$. Now
\begin{aligned}
H_i:=U\left[\pmatrix{D_i\\ &0}-cI_m\right]U^\ast
&=U\pmatrix{D_i\\ &0}U^\ast-cI_m\\
&=\pmatrix{P\\ Q}D_i\pmatrix{P^\ast& Q^\ast}-cI_m\\
&=\pmatrix{PD_iP^\ast&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}-cI_m\\
&=\pmatrix{A_i+cI_n&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}-cI_m\\
&=\pmatrix{A_i&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}.\\
\end{aligned}
Hence $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two commuting Hermitian matrices with $A_1$ and $A_2$ as their respective leading principal submatrices.

Comment: Why it's only *partial* answer?

Comment: @narip When $n\ge2$, in order that the embedding is always possible, a simple dimension argument shows that $m$ must be at least $3n/2$, but I don't know what is the best possible $m$.

Comment: Is there some references about properties of encoding an hermitian matrix or just a matrix into a larger one? I can't find any in matrix analysis books or googleing embedding matrices. Thanks!

Comment: @narip Sorry, I am not familiar with this area of research. The paper “[*Minimal normal and commuting completions*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1050.360&rep=rep1&type=pdf)” by Kimsey and Woerdeman is probably relevant, but while you consider the embedding of Hermitian matrices into commuting matrices, the paper considers two other problems, namely, (1) the embedding of two matrices into two commuting normal matrices (sections 1-3), and (2) the general embedding problem of two matrices into two commuting matrices (section 4). ...

Comment: ...Another research topic that is related but different from yours is the study of near commuting matrices. That is, given two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size, such that $\|[A,B]\|$ is small, we ask whether there exist two commuting matrices $A'$ and $B'$ such that $\|A-A'\|$ and $\|B-B'\|$ are also small. See [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/68367) for instance.